# How do you fix memory leaks in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud function that is involved with in a data loading process (CSV in a Google Bucket -> Cloud SQL).

The cloud function was hitting memory issues while handling a larger file, and as I began to iterate and re-deploy, I started receiving the following error:

> Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
>   "errorMessage": "`yarn_install` had stderr output:\nwarning
>   package.json: No license field\nFATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector:
>   semi-space copy, fallback in old gen Allocation failed - JavaScript
>   heap out of memory\n 1: 0x55ed663dfc50 node::Abort() [node]\n 2:
>   0x55ed663dfc9e [node]\n 3: 0x55ed6660e462
>   v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool)
>   [node]\n 4: 0x55ed6660e7b8
>   v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
>   const*, bool) [node]\n 5: 0x55ed66a61462 [node]\n 6: 0x55ed66a8e274
>   v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor::Visit(v8::internal::HeapObject*,
>   int) [node]\n 7: 0x55ed66a92957 void
>   v8::internal::LiveObjectVisitor::VisitBlackObjectsNoFail(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*,
>   v8::internal::MajorNonAtomicMarkingState*,
>   v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor*,
>   v8::internal::LiveObjectVisitor::IterationMode) [node]\n 8:
>   0x55ed66a9acc9
>   v8::internal::FullEvacuator::RawEvacuatePage(v8::internal::Page*,
>   long*) [node]\n 9: 0x55ed66a89569
>   v8::internal::Evacuator::EvacuatePage(v8::internal::Page*) [node]\n10:
>   0x55ed66a898a2 v8::internal::PageEvacuationTask::RunInParallel()
>   [node]\n11: 0x55ed66a823df
>   v8::internal::ItemParallelJob::Task::RunInternal() [node]\n12:
>   0x55ed66a8323d
>   v8::internal::ItemParallelJob::Run(std::shared_ptr)
>   [node]\n13: 0x55ed66a8edc1 void
>   v8::internal::MarkCompactCollectorBase::CreateAndExecuteEvacuationTasks(v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector*,
>   v8::internal::ItemParallelJob*,
>   v8::internal::RecordMigratedSlotVisitor*,
>   v8::internal::MigrationObserver*, long) [node]\n14: 0x55ed66a99bb7
>   v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuatePagesInParallel()
>   [node]\n15: 0x55ed66a99d2b
>   v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuate() [node]\n16:
>   0x55ed66a9a73d v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage()
>   [node]\n17: 0x55ed66a71789 v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact()
>   [node]\n18: 0x55ed66a72023
>   v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector,
>   v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]\n19: 0x55ed66a72aff
>   v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace,
>   v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags)
>   [node]\n20: 0x55ed66a75315
>   v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int,
>   v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
>   [node]\n21: 0x55ed66a3c164 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int,
>   bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [node]\n22: 0x55ed66d1059e
>   v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**,
>   v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]\n23: 0x31bac4adbe1d \n\nerror:
>   `yarn_install` returned code: -6", "errorType": "InternalError",
>   "errorId": "5A8D99A0"}}

I only have a small handful of libraries in my package.json so its surprising to see this issue.

It seems like I am hitting a memory leak in my GCP hosted function so I tried deleting the function and re-deploying (in hopes of getting a new container/machine) to no success. I've also tried upgrade libraries, re-deploy existing code, and deploying from different machines with no success.

Currently using the following:

- Node10
- Google Cloud SDK 285.0.1
- bq 2.0.55
- core 2020.03.17
- gsutil 4.48

Answer (score 1):

It seemed like a dependency (which had been installed for quite some time) was suddenly causing issues during the `yarn install` process. I had the @google-cloud/functions-framework@1.1.0 installed, and after removing it, my build process completed fine (I also tried upgrading to the latest @1.5.0 to no avail).

`yarn remove @google-cloud/functions-framework` allowed me to re-deploy successfully